# How to make Excel file that has been converted to JSON load to table (DataTables) automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, object

so i got this assigment, i need to load CSV file into html page, 
after i loaded it, i need to make a code that run automatically - 
getting the object field name - put it in the table head, and the match the value to each of the object field name.
everything neeed to be automtically (because our teacher is going to check just by adding the csv file - nothing can be hard coded.
we also need to use library called Data Tables.

i managed to do some of the assigment, but most of it is hard coded so it is not good.

here is my html -

```
  <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr id="FieldNames">

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Values">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and to thid table i added this code - 
(with hard coded JSON just to see if i can do it before i import CSV file)

```
const Json = 
            [
{
                "name": "john",
                "age": 35,
                "email": "AF@asdsa.com",
                "address": "Rishon LeZion"
            },
            {
                "name": "hezi",
                "age": 31,
                "email": "wertwree@grf.com",
                "address": "Rishon LeZion"

            },
            {
                "name": "david",
                "age": 23,
                "email": "wertewrt@fd.com",
                "address": "Rishon LeZion"
            },
            {
                "name": "jacky",
                "age": 41,
                "email": "wertr@aa.com",
                "address": "Rishon LeZion"
            }];



        $(document).ready(function () {
            var Obj = Json[0];
            var KeyNames = Object.keys(Obj)
            for (let i = 0; i < KeyNames.length; i++) {
                var Head = $(`<th>${KeyNames[i]}</th>`);
                $("#FieldNames").append(Head);
            }
            for (let j = 0; j < Json.length; j++) {
                var firstVal =  Json[j].name
                var secondVal = Json[j].age
                var thirdVal =  Json[j].email
                var fourthVal = Json[j].address
              var Data = `
              <tr class="middle">
                <td>${firstVal}</td>
                <td>${secondVal}</td>
                <td>${thirdVal}</td>
                <td>${fourthVal}</td>
              </tr>
              `;
              $("#Values").append(Data);
            }

            $('#table_id').DataTable();
        });
```

even though the result is good, it is not what i asked to do.
im trying to figure out ways to make it run automatically but it's not working so well for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did it a while ago, here's the solution:

I separated my logic into two sections:

1) Create headers:

Loop through the children Objects (as in the Objects in the array) and then get their keys with `Object.keys()`
The keys are your headers. Then throw them in a row inside thead and voila, your headers

2) Create the fields. This is a bit more complicated.
Loop through the main objects and that will give you the objects one by one as the loop unfolds. Then, create a row for each index. Get the values of each object, and make sure you throw them in the correct row as a `td` by doing something like I did `id='object-" + childIndex + "'`. Then grab that specific row, and after you get `Object.values()` from your object, throw them one by one with a loop inside of the row. TA DA

P.S. Don't ask me why I used jquery. I used it because I'm not a masochist to do this with pure JS

```js
const json = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": 35,
    "email": "AF@asdsa.com",
    "address": "Rishon LeZion"
  },
  {
    "name": "hezi",
    "age": 31,
    "email": "wertwree@grf.com",
    "address": "Rishon LeZion"

  },
  {
    "name": "david",
    "age": 23,
    "email": "wertewrt@fd.com",
    "address": "Rishon LeZion"
  },
  {
    "name": "jacky",
    "age": 41,
    "email": "wertr@aa.com",
    "address": "Rishon LeZion"
  }
];

//get headers and create them
const table = $("table");
const thead = $("thead");

var promiseMe = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  //to create the headers first based on the objects
  var createHeaders = json.forEach((childObjects, index) => {
    const kNames = Object.keys(childObjects);

    for (let [index, name] of kNames.entries()) {
      const actualName = name.replace(/\s+/g, '')
      let divId = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
      let element = document.getElementById(divId);

      if (!element) {
        thead.append("<td class='header-name' id='" + divId + "'>" + name + "</td>")
      }
    }

    resolve(createHeaders);
  })
}).then(createFields());

function createFields() {
  const keyNames = Object.values(json);

  keyNames.forEach((childObject, childIndex) => {
    //create a row for each object
    const valArray = Object.values(childObject);

    $("#Values").append("<tr id='object-" + childIndex + "' class='rows table-row'></tr>")

    valArray.forEach((value, index) => {
      $("#object-" + childIndex).append("<td class='cell'>" + value + "</td>")
    })

  })
}
```

```css
.cell, .header-name  {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Values">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, you helped me so much - not taken from granted at all.

Comment: Cheers man, I'm glad I did. If you didn't notice, with my approach it doesn't matter how long your jsv is (flat json objects are called jsv), the code will never stop working.

Comment: this is really amazing.
i got more 1 more question (if it's okay)
im trying to find a way to load local CSV file to the my html (without using Ajax)
and its not working well for me. do you know any good method?

Comment: @Àtishking Ahhh unfortunately this is where my js knowledge is finished, because this is something you'd do in the backend and backend-wise, I'm .NET. If it was C# I could help you (I've done it 100 times in C#). BUT, your best bet here is to google it and not try to reinvent the wheel. Someone must have done some of the work for you.

Comment: Actually it's only client side! the file is alerady located locally in the same directory as the html file, i only need to find a way to parse it. but thank you anyways!!! you helped me alot.

Comment: @Àtishking Take my word for it. A file that needs to become a view (basically) is something the backend should handle. Anyway, cheers. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Àtishking I found this. Seems like what you want: https://gist.github.com/theredstapler/5ce6a43b066dbe0cac3fa5587835be91